# Without using if statement, how can i return value with exceptional condition

Tags: java

```
package src;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class Sum {

public static int maxSubsequence(int[] arr) {
    int s;
    
    
    if(){
     for(int i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if((arr[i]<0)||(arr.length==0)){
       s=0;
    }
     }
    
    
    else{
    int max_sum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    int end_sum = 0;

   for(int k : arr){

       end_sum = Math.max(end_sum+k, k);

       max_sum = Math.max(end_sum,max_sum);
   }
   s = max_sum;
    }
    
    
    
   
  return s;

}
}
```

Problem

It's Kadane algorithm.
With the two exceptional condition.

condition 1: if all array is empty, return 0.

condition 2: if all array value is negative, return 0.

what can i do for the first if() condition?

Comment: You set ```s``` to max_sum, regardless of your if statement. Start by not doing that :)

Comment: How can i  let those exceptional condition return 0?

Comment: The obvious way is "write an if statement", so why are you opposed to that?   You yourself describe them as "exceptional conditions", meaning not a result reachable by the normal processing.

Comment: mmm yes i will update my code. soon

Comment: WHy cannot you not use a standard feature of the langauge. Use an IF statement!

Comment: Please try to fix your weird code formatting. It tames the motivation to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

If somehow needed, it would be possible to write them all without `if statement` though...?

```
public static int maxSubsequence(int[] arr) {

    int s;
    int max_sum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    int end_sum = 0;
    int neg_sum = 0;

    for(int k : arr) {
        neg_sum += Math.max(-1, k);
        end_sum = Math.max(end_sum + k, k);

        max_sum = Math.max(end_sum, max_sum);
    }
    s = Math.min(neg_sum + arr.length, 1) * max_sum;
    return s;
}
```